# How can i make that in the List codec's it will also show me the type of each codec?

Tags: c++-cli

The type of each codec or the type of the codec's
In the List i have in the end about 500 codec's i want that for example in the List in the beginning it will show for example:

**Audio**
mpeha
mpegv
.....
**Video**
xvid
divx

And so on.

The first two functions to get the List of codec's are in C:

```
const char* Encoder_GetNextCodecName()
{
    current_codec = av_codec_next(current_codec);
    while (current_codec != NULL)
    {       
        return current_codec->name;
    }
    return "";
}

const char* Encoder_GetFirstCodecName()
{
    current_codec = NULL;
    return Encoder_GetNextCodecName();
}
```

Then i have header file:

```
const char* Encoder_GetNextCodecName();
const char* Encoder_GetFirstCodecName();
```

Then another C++ header file where i create the List:

```
List<String^> ^GetCodecs()
    {
        List<String^> ^l = gcnew List<String^>;

        String ^s = gcnew String(Encoder_GetFirstCodecName());
        while (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            l->Add(s);
            s = gcnew String(Encoder_GetNextCodecName());
        }

        return l;
     }
```

Then when i'm doing in CSHARP this:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>(f.GetCodecs());
```

I see that the variable l containing 506 codec's .
The codec's are of ffmpeg !!!

Now in the C file there is also something like:

```
current_codec->type
```

Which have many properties.
And there is also something like this in the C file:

```
AVMediaType::
```

Which give me a 7 categories of types of the codec's.

The problem is how do i make in the C++ header file when i create the List that the List will be with the types of each codec or of each group of codec's like : Audio,Video,Data.... ?

**EDIT**

This is another header file i have that is connecting between the C functions and the CLI:

I have another header file where i first call the functions from C:

```
ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#include <stdint.h>

bool Encoder_MoveToNextCodec();
bool Encoder_MoveToFirstCodec();
const char* Encoder_GetCurrentCodecName();
int Encoder_GetCurrentCodecType();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}    // extern "C"
#endif
```

This is my CLI code:

```
#pragma once



// FFMPEG_WRAPPER.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//
#include "ENCODER.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <vcclr.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Drawing::Imaging;

using namespace msclr::interop;

namespace MyVideo
{

public ref class FFMPEGWrapper
{
public:
    FFMPEGWrapper(void)
    {

        Encoder_init();

    }

ref class CodecInfo
{
public:
    String^ CodecName;
    int CodecType;
};

List<CodecInfo^> ^GetCodecs()
{
    List<CodecInfo^> ^l = gcnew List<CodecInfo^>;

    bool KeepLooping = Encoder_MoveToFirstCodec();
    while (KeepLooping)
    {
        CodecInfo ^codec = gcnew CodecInfo();

        codec->CodecName = gcnew String(Encoder_GetCurrentCodecName());
        codec->CodecType = Encoder_GetCurrentCodecType();


        l->Add(codec);
        KeepLooping = Encoder_MoveToNextCodec();
    }

    return l;
 }
```

Then in CSHARP i did:

```
List<f.CodecInfo> l = f.GetCodecs();
```

But CodecInfo is not exist and i'm getting an error on the GetCodecs()

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Error   2   'ScreenVideoRecorder.Form1.f' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

The problems the errors are in CSHARP.

Comment: The language you are using is not C and not C++. It's called "C++/CLI". Despite having "C++" in its name, it's very different from C++. Tags updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand your C code to expose the extra details you want, eg:

```
__declspec(thread) AVCodec* current_codec = NULL;

bool Encoder_MoveToNextCodec()
{
    current_codec = av_codec_next(current_codec);
    return (current_codec != NULL);
}

bool Encoder_MoveToFirstCodec()
{
    current_codec = NULL;
    return Encoder_MoveToNextCodec();
}

const char* Encoder_GetCurrentCodecName()
{
    if (current_codec != NULL)
        return current_codec->name;
    return "";
}

int Encoder_GetCurrentCodecType()
{
    if (current_codec != NULL)
        return (int) current_codec->type;
    return AVMEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
}
```

Then expand your CLI code to store that info:

```
ref class CodecInfo
{
public:
    String^ CodecName;
    int CodecType;
    ...
};

List<CodecInfo^> ^GetCodecs()
{
    List<CodecInfo^> ^l = gcnew List<CodecInfo^>;

    bool KeepLooping = Encoder_MoveToFirstCodec();
    while (KeepLooping)
    {
        CodecInfo ^codec = gcnew CodecInfo();

        codec->CodecName = gcnew String(Encoder_GetCurrentCodecName());
        codec->CodecType = Encoder_GetCurrentCodecType();
        ...

        l->Add(codec);
        KeepLooping = Encoder_MoveToNextCodec();
    }

    return l;
 }
```

Then lastly, use the new info as needed:

```
List<CodecInfo> l = f.GetCodecs();
foreach(CodecInfo codec in l)
{
    // use codec.CodecName, codec.CodecType, ... as needed
}
```

Comment: Remy in CSHARP there is no List<CodecInfo> the CodecInfo is not exist.

Comment: Remy i'm updating my question please look on it.

Comment: Updated my question with the errors and the problem in CSHARP

Comment: @YaronCohenMinz: Obviously, you would have to define a `CodecInfo` type in C# that matches the one in C++CLI.